# how to modify JavaScript before it runs in the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to modify JavaScript before it runs in the Chrome browser. For example, if I have the following in the html page:

```
<script>alert('gotcha!');</script>
```

I want to replace this JS using the chrome extension before that alerts pops up. So far, I tried using DOMContentLoaded like this but it does not work:

```
function fireContentLoadedEvent () {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("
    <script>alert('gotcha!');</script>", "");
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fireContentLoadedEvent, false);
```

Comment: Chrome can't intercept script elements before the code executes. The only lame but workable method is to rewrite the entire page html like [uBlock Extra does via document.open() + document.write()](https://github.com/gorhill/uBO-Extra/blob/master/contentscript.js#L246-L269) in a content script executed before the page is processed ("run_at": "document_start" in manifest's declaration of the content script).

Comment: wOxxOm, on what event can page re-writing  can be done before that JavaScript gets executed?

Comment: There's no event. Put some effort into checking the code I've linked.